# C# Using a string to name an instance of a class

Tags: c#, class, variables

In the code below, I'd like to make a new instance of 'BoxID' and have it named after the contents of the string in the line above.

```
for (int i = 0; i < idCount; i++)
        {
            string nextID = File.ReadAllLines(IDFILELOCATION).Skip(i).Take(1).First();
            BoxID nextID = new BoxID("", "", "", false, 0, 0, 0);
        }
```

Have been ripping my hair out for the last hour over how to do this so any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a variable whose name is determined at runtime?

Comment: Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: How would you then write code that uses those variables if you don't know their name???

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify:

Comment: What you mean by "named".  Variables have names (for example, you have a `BoxID` variable named `nextID` in your code.  Objects don't have names.  They may have a (likely string) property called `Name`.  They may be collected in a `Dictionary<string, YourClass>` and be effectively named by the key to which the object is associated.  But, they don't have a "name".  In particular, if you collect them in a dictionary, the object being collected doesn't know to which key is is associated.  Similarly, objects don't know the names of any variables that refer to the object

Comment: And, oh, looking over your code... You really want to take the call to `File.ReadAllLines` out of your loop.  You are going to read the contents of that file over and over, `idCount` times they way it's written.  Before the `for` statement, do something like `var lines = File.ReadAllLines(IDFILELOCATION);`.  Then, in the loop, use `lines.Skip(i).Take(1).First();`

Comment: Or, even better, once you get the `lines` variable holding that array of lines you have read, you can just `foreach (var line in lines) { /* do what you intend to do in that loop */}`

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a dictionary.

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, BoxID>();
 dictionary.Add("myVariableName", new BoxID("", "", "", false, 0, 0, 0));

 // To retrieve it
 var myBoxID = dictionary["myVariableName"];
```

That's the only way I know of to do it without knowing the names of your variables at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit unclear, is this the answer you are looking for?

```
// Create string array of the lines you want
var array_of_lines = File.ReadAllLines(IDFILELOCATION).Skip(1).ToArray();

// Using the linq select method, create a BoxID instance for each line in the array_of_lines
var array_of_boxids = array_of_lines.Select(line => 
{
    // Do something with the "line" variable
    return new BoxID("", "", "", false, 0, 0, 0);
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. 

I did a terrible job of explaining that but somehow you understood. My bad for making it so complicated

Comment: No problem, I hope I didn't put you off by using the ".Select()" method, it saves you having to populate a "List<>". If you want I can also show how to do it using "for()", the main incorrect thing you did was creating the line array / reading the file each time you iterate. Also using your "Skip(i).First()" line should be done with the brackets [i].